# Can google map V2 (Android) location update work with Cell Tower ONLY?

Tags: android, location, google-maps-android-api-2, location-client

I have been developing an Android App using google maps API v2 and implements LocationClient to retrieve user's current location. The problem is if the wifi and gps are not enabled, only mobile network (with H+ connection) is enabled, the "OnLocationChanged()" is never been called. If the wifi or gps is enabled, then everything works fine.

The same thing happens to the demo apps, "LocationUpdates".

This was tested on Samsung S3, Android version 4.1.2

My question here is whether the location update request can work without the wifi and gps but with mobile network ONLY.

Thank you and sorry if this was asked somewhere else.

Comment: If you use GoogleServices, try setting LocationRequest with setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY). Also not that the documentation states that PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY is more likely to use WIFI & Cell tower positioning, but it also depends on many other factors (such as which sources are available) and is implementation dependent. If you don't then try LocationManager, it allows you set set criteria using Criteria class

Comment: Did u get solution already ? I am facing same issue. Thanks

Comment: Hi Maneti, it works fine after updating the Android SDK, Google play services rev 12 that I'm using now. The location can be found even without wifi/gps, just that it will be taking longer time.